# If 'C' inherits from 'B' publicly, B inherits from 'A' privately, Why can't I create an object of 'A' inside 'C'?

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, access-modifiers, name-lookup

I'm using Visual C++, If I compile this code:

```
class A {};
class B : private A {};
class C : public B
{
    void func()
    {
        A a{};
    }
};
```

I get this error:

> error C2247: 'A' not accessible because 'B' uses 'private' to inherit
>   from 'A'

I know that if I use private inheritance, Then the members of the class 'A' would be private in 'B', And inaccessible in 'C', But why can't I create an object of 'A' inside 'C'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the name `A` inside the scope of the class C is a private name.

It is a so-called injected class name.

From the C++ Standard (6.3.2 Point of declaration)

> 8 The point of declaration for an injected-class-name (Clause 12) is
>   immediately following the opening brace of the class definition.

Use the following approach that is use the qualified name

```
class A {};
class B : private A {};
class C : public B
{
    void func()
    {
        ::A a{};
      //^^^^^^ 
    }
};
```